# C++ Intellisense providing duplicates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

See image below. I'm currently coding in C++. Intellisense is giving me duplicate suggestions. I'd prefer to only see one of each. How can I fix this?

[image: Image of Duplicates]

Edit: Link to download the code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1npd0QMHCU7pRmkAa9LvjR5GPfirIeqRU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think those are overloads instead of duplicates.

Comment: Can you please post the code and not an image of the code? Thanks.

Comment: @Borgleader: It's not code.

Comment: If they are overloads, is there a way I can condense them into one and only access the overloads through the signature?